# Express server for an artists website

Tags: javascript, server, express.js

I am currently creating a website for an artist (my grandfather). My main concern with the code below is readability, as for the most part I have not worked with others on a (programming) project. I use a few external modules but hopefully their purpose is obvious/irrelevant.

I have been programming with javascript as a hobby for about two years.

Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const gzip = require('express-gzip')
const handleRequest = require('./handleRequest')
const verify = require('../Admin/login').verify

app.use(gzip)
app.use(express.json())

app.get(['/bio', '/contact', '/login', '/works', '/404', '/bug', '/edit-bio', '/edit-works'], (req, res) => verify(req.query.token).then(result => fs.readFile((req.path === '/edit-bio' || req.path === '/edit-works' ? result : true) ? ((result && req.path === '/login') ? '../../Frontend/html/edit-works.html' : `../../Frontend/html${req.path}.html`) : '../../Frontend/html/login.html', (err, data) => err ? res.status(500).end() : res.end(data))))
app.get('/', (_req, res) => fs.readFile('../../Frontend/index.html', (err, data) => err ? res.status(500).end() : res.end(data)))
app.post(/.+/, (req, res) => handleRequest[req.body.type](req.body).then(result => result.err ? res.status(500).end(JSON.stringify(result.data)) : res.end(JSON.stringify(result.data))))

app.use('/html', (_req, res) => res.status(404).redirect('/404'))
app.use(express.static('../../Frontend'))
app.use((_req, res) => (res.status(404).redirect('/404'))).listen(8080)
```

This is a simple express server that answers get requests on: `'/bio'`, `'/contact'`, `'/login'`, etc. If the request is to `'/edit-bio'` or `'/edit-works'` it verifies a jwt provided in the query string. If it receives a post request of any kind it runs a function corresponding to a `type` property in that request. It also has a simple 404 page. Finally it uses `express.static` on a `Frontend` folder containing the css, js, html, etc.

Comment: What's the deal with lines of code hundreds of characters wide?  That ruins the readability in many circumstances (like here).  Also, usually you wouldn't manually be comparing a lot of paths in your routes.  Instead, use your route definitions to focus on a specific route and then if you want to share code between routes, either use middleware or call shared functions from different route handlers.  You don't typically want to see `app.get([...])` with a whole bunch of separate paths for the same route and then code inside the route handler to separate out the routes.  Make different routes.

Comment: And, you can probably use `express.static()` in one middleware configuration for all your static routes rather than manually doing `fs.readFile()` and `res.end()` for each one separately.

Comment: @jfriend00 are you saying that I should use `express.static()` and then reroute the requests to the paths to the HTML file? And then replace `app.use('/html', (_req, res) => res.status(404).redirect('/404'))` with `app.use(['/html/edit-bio', '/html/edit-works'], (_req, res) => res.status(404).redirect('/404'))`?

Comment: Let's just start by you should increase the readability of the `app.get(['/bio', '/contact', '/login', '/works', '/404', '/bug', '/edit-bio', '/edit-works'] ...` line of code.  Even after putting it into an editor and breaking it into multiple lines, it still isn't obvious to me what that line does except that it's got multiple checks for various paths which means you aren't taking advantage of the simplicity of using separate route declarations for separate paths.   And, I can't imagine how one would add three more routes to it without a pretty good change of breaking something.

Comment: Maybe if I have a lot more patience sometime in the future, I'll finally figure out what that line is supposed to do an rewrite it into separate routes or figure out what can just be done with `express.static()`.  But, the MAIN point is that that line is not easily readable.  Probably several different approaches to simplify it.

Comment: To simplify that line, I'd need to know what `verify()` does?  Does it reject?  Does it send a response under any conditions?  What is the result for?

Comment: `verify()` is a function that verifies a json web token. It will either return true or false depending on whether or not the token is valid.

Comment: So, at least separate into different route definitions the paths that care about calling `verify()` from the paths that don't.  And, I don't see why you can't use `express.static()` for these routes: `['/bio', '/contact', '/login', '/works', '/404', '/bug'],`.  They don't appear to have any special processing.

Comment: @jfriend00 alright, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Rewrite the line of code `app.get(['/bio', '/contact', '/login', '/works', '/404', '/bug', '/edit-bio', '/edit-works'] ...` to be readable and maintainable and debuggable.  It should likely be broken into at least two separate routes.
2. Separate into different route definitions the paths that care about calling `verify()` and the ones that don't.
3. Use express.static for routes that don't appear to have any special processing such as `['/bio', '/contact', '/login', '/works', '/404', '/bug']`.
4. Use `res.sendFile()` instead of repeating this `err ? res.status(500).end() : res.end(data)` over and over again.
5. Put your verify logic into a middleware format so it can easily be attached to any route.